# Agm-core + google maps heatmaps - very slow page

Tags: angular, google-maps, heatmap

So the issue is that there are a lot of things going on on the screen for me, and the whole page turns very slow as soon as I turn on google heatmaps.

I have a google maps, with around 200 markers, which are updated automatically. Each marker receives update socket event from the server and updates itself. The map is quite responsive with the 200 markers updating, and I can move around and interact (it's a little bit laggy, but I would say really responsive with the amount of markers and requests).

The issue arises when google heatmaps are turned on. It takes around 2 seconds to load the heatmap, and afterwards, if I want to zoom in/out or move the map, it takes around 4 to 5 seconds to do the action.

So currently here is the heatmap creation code

```
            const coords = [{
              weight: 1,
              location: new google.maps.LatLng(heatmapMarker.container_latitude, heatmapMarker.container_longitude)
            }];

            const heatmap = new google.maps.visualization.HeatmapLayer({
              map: this.google_map,
              data: coords,
              radius: 20
            });

            heatmap.set('gradient', heatmapMarker.gradient);

            this.assignedHeatmaps.push({ marker: heatmapMarker.id, map: heatmap, data: heatmapMarker.data });
```

So in total it does not make difference if I add 1 heatmap layer, or 10 - in all scenarions, as soon as heatmaps are added to the map, it gets really slow.

I'm not sure from where to start to debug the code...

Any suggestions?

My desired result would be that heatmaps would run faster, and would not take multiple seconds to finish an action, after I've enabled heatmaps.

Comment: Best way to achieve this use `*ngIf` and with a boolean flag while all operations are complete then load google map component by setting the value to true of flag.

Comment: @AlokeT the google map itself loads pretty fast, as well as, the heatmaps are loaded and displayed fast. But as soon as they are displayed, the map is really slow.

Comment: I think `AGM` component trying to do some background work with Angular, and Angular also try to doing some basic work within itself, so, either you load `AGM` component late or update it outside the angular life-cycle by using `NgZone`.

Comment: @AlokeT wanna add an answer regarding NgZone? I'll accept it, since it resolved my issue.